# Logcat standalone client

Tags: android, testing, stack-trace, logcat

I have developed android application. Now it is time to give it to the beta testers.

Is there a standalone application that will collect LogCat output? I do not want to force testers to install the whole android development environment. I was thinking about an application that will collect logs through USB port and display them to the PC console (logging to the SD card is not that convenient), so that tester could provide a crash trace or some debugging info.

Comment: `adb logcat` will work without having to install eclipse, but you will need to at least download the SDK.  The SDK itself is pretty small so long as you don't download the libraries for the specific android builds.  The package you download contains all of the tools, like adb, for that sort of thing.  Would that work?

Comment: thx Chris, `adb` standalone can be downloaded from this site: http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/index.php?title=ADB

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`adb logcat` standalone app is the answer.

It can be downloaded from [this site](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/index.php?title=ADB).

Comment: The link you provided is no longer accessible. You probably meant this program: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=638150

Answer (score 4):

Yes, **[android-log-collector](http://code.google.com/p/android-log-collector/)**. This app is really helpful... the testers just have to installing, and when they need to send a log trace, just execute this app and choose how to send the logcat to you (email, for instance).

Comment: It seems it doesn't collect the logcat entries, but fetches system info only.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a mac, you can always give a try to: https://github.com/YANOUSHek/LogCat